# How can I draw this diagram where gradients are drawn in xy-plane

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

How can I draw this picture using tikz so gradients are drawn in xy-plane. Or maybe an animation so the concept of gradient become clear or easy to understand.

Comment: Do you know the function that is plotting the surface? `pgfplots` should be able to do this for you (adapting something from here: http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html), and I'd be happy to have a go if you can provide a function.

Comment: f(x,y)=x^2+y^2. Actually the function does not matter. It can be any function of two variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution using `TikZ` and `pgfplots`. You insert the function on the line indicated, and the derivatives w.r.t. x and y also as indicated.

Depending on the function, you may need to adjust the arrow lengths, which can be achieved by adjusting `quiver/scale arrows=0.1` to something else (e.g. make `0.1` smaller or bigger). You can also adjust the size of the domain where indicated.

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    domain=-1:1,
    xmax=1,
    ymax=1,
]
\addplot3[blue,/pgfplots/quiver,
    quiver/u=2*x, % derivative w.r.t. x
    quiver/v=2*y, % derivative w.r.t. y
    quiver/w=0,
    quiver/scale arrows=0.1,
    -stealth,samples=10] {-2};
\addplot3[mesh,draw=blue] {x^2+y^2}; % function
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Plot of z equals x squared plus y squared]

For further ideas of what can be done, there are a huge number of examples of the use of `pgfplot` here: http://pgfplots.sourceforge.net/gallery.html

Comment: +1: Amazingly compact code! `pgfplots` is great.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with rbrignall that one can use quiver plots here. However, there are a number of points that I'd like to add

1. If you have a slowly varying function you can let pgfplots compute the derivatives.
2. Since the function is slowly varying you need to scale the arrows quite a bit.
3. You benefit from indicating `compat=1.16`. The old compatibility mode is quite different from the most recent one.
4. You need `3d box=complete` to have a complete box.

Result (using a function that is reminiscent of your screen shot):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16,width=12cm}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[declare function={f(\x,\y)=0.5-pow(cos(\x)*cos(\y),2)-pow(cos(\x),2)-pow(cos(\y),2)
  -0.5*pow(sin(\x)*sin(\y),2);},
  zmin=-4.001,zmax=0.001,
  domain=-90:90,ytick={-90,0,90},xtick={-90,0,90},
  view={145}{30},3d box=complete]
\addplot3[color=blue,quiver={
    u={(f(x+1,y)-f(x-1,y))},
    v={(f(x,y+1)-f(x,y-1))}, 
    w value=0,
    scale arrows=180},
    every arrow/.append style={line width=0.2pt},
    %quiver/scale arrows=0.1,
    -stealth,samples=15] {-4};
\addplot3[mesh,draw=blue] {f(x,y)}; % function
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]